# Treat file as a different file type for syntax linting color purposes in Vim

Tags: vim, colors

I know there's a command to treat your current file as a different file type for linting / color purposes.

Something like

```
:set SomethingICantRemember='python'
```

And it will change the colors of the words of your current file as if it were a `.py` file. I've used this before when viewing uncommon file types, like `.conkyrc`, but I can't remember what I used. If anyone knows, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
:set syntax=python:
```

See
[Modeline magic](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Modeline_magic)
for more details.